# In Django, how to delete exclusive many-to-many objects for a parent object?

Tags: python, django, django-models

My Django App has an Organisation model. An organisation may be identified by many aliases but these aliases may not be unique to that organisation.

For example:
Imperial College London (imperial.ac.uk) - may have an alias of ICL.
The ICL Group (icl-group.com) - may share the same alias of ICL.

In order to cater for this I have defined a ManyToMany relationship:

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
   ...
   aliases = models.ManyToManyField(OrgAlias)
   ...
```

Currently, when I delete an organisation, I need to manually check all of its associated aliases and delete those that aliases aren't attached to another organisation.

Is there a way to automatically cascade deletions of aliases that are exclusive to the organisation being deleted.

I briefly explored pre_delete signals. If this is the way to go, can anyone provide an example? Alternatively if there is a better route, would appreciate the guidance.

Comment: In that case that would more be a post-delete signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the `OrgAlias`ses that are not connected to any `Organization` with:

```
OrgAlias.objects.filter(organization=None)
```

You can try to run this as a post-delete signal with:

```
OrgAlias.objects.filter(organization=None).delete()
```

But likely it is better to only show `OrgAlias`es that have at least one organization when you need to list these:

```
OrgAlias.objects.filter(organization__isnull=False).distinct()
```

and make a [*management command* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-management-commands/#command-objects) that periodically removes "dead" `OrgAlias`ses:

```
# app_name/management/commands/clean_empty_aliasses.py

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        OrgAlias.objects.filter(organization=None).delete()
```

then you can run this with:

```
$ manage.py clean_empty_aliasses
```

Comment: Thanks for this info. Had no idea that it was possible to hook into the manage.py command system. Great info.

However, I went with a pre_delete signal approach to save the additional complexity involved in setting up and scheduling cleaning operations. Answer below.

Comment: @TheHelQ: signals are often *by far* the worst option, especially since signals to do *not* run with bulk operations (removing items in bulk): https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html

Answer (score 0):

I went with the pre_delete signal approach here. I want the cleaning to be done at the time of deletion, so decided a signal is the best way to go. Code below:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Organisation)
def delete_exclusive_aliases(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    for alias in instance.aliases.all():
        if len(alias.organisation_set.all()) == 1:
            alias.delete()
```